# rails link_to_add_fields not adding fields with has_many :through (with nested form inside)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have the link_to_add_fields code working for many other models, but here it is not working.  I use Ryan Bates screen casts to model how I do mine.

What might different with this is that I have 2 nested models in one partial. Half the table fields are from model a (journals), and the other are from model b (journal_entries) and all are based off a Leases model.

The table looks like the following, [xx] are input fields. It looks kinda like a data grid.

```
Dated      |Memo      |Account           |Credit     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
[a.dated]  |[a.memo]  |[b.account_name]  |[b.credit] |....
[a.dated]  |[a.memo]  |[b.account_name]  |[b.credit] |....
[a.dated]  |[a.memo]  |[b.account_name]  |[b.credit] |....
(Link:Click to add another row)
```

When I inspect the link_to_add_fields in the produced html is see:

```
<a href="#" class="add_fields" data-fields="&lt;fieldset style=&quot;
border:0px none;padding:0px .625em;&quot;&gt;  &lt;/fieldset&gt;" 
data-id="-629772378">+ Add transactions</a>
```

I expected a lot more action than that... Obviously when I click the link, nothing happens.

_journals_form.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= f.fields_for :journals do |journals| %>
    <%= render "journal_fields" , {f: journals} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add transactions", f, :journals %>
</div>
```

_journal_fields.html.erb, Notice the nested f.fields_for and the mix of f.attribute and g.attribute

```
<fieldset style="border:0px none;padding:0px .625em;">
  <%= f.fields_for :journal_entries do |g| %> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:200px;font-size:.7em"><%= f.date_select :dated %></td>
          ...
          <td style="width:100px;"><%= g.text_field :account_name, size: 8 %></td>
          <td style="width:100px;"><%= g.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

My controller appears to edit/update and add rows of both models (journals and journal_entries) except that the remove link is buggy...

```
  def edit
    @lease = Lease.find(params[:id])
    @lease.tenants.build
    1.times do 
      journal = @lease.journals.build
      journal.journal_entries.build
    end
  end
  def update
    @lease = Lease.find(params[:id])
    if @lease.update_attributes(params[:lease])
      redirect_to edit_pm_lease_path(@lease), notice: 'Lease was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end
```

The model is based off Leases.  Leases have many journals and many journal entries through journals.  This is how we keep track of payments and bills for a given lease.  Leases also has many tenants (and this add_fields... works great).

Lease.rb

```
class Lease < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :tenants
  has_many :journals, :order => [:dated, :id] #, :conditions => "journals.lease_id = id"
  has_many :journal_entries, :through => :journals  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenants , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journal_entries , :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journals ,  :allow_destroy => true    
  #Below didn't seem to help or hinder so it's removed.
    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :journals, :journal_entries, :allow_destroy => true 
  ...
end
```

journal.rb

```
class Journal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... 
  belongs_to :lease, :conditions =>  :lease_id != nil   
  has_many :journal_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journal_entries , :allow_destroy => true
end
```

journal_entry.rb

```
class JournalEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :journal
end
```

link_to_add_fields helper: (References from Ryan bates railscasts (EPISODE #196)

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def external_link_to(label, target, options = [])
    #length = 25 #options[:length] ||= 25
    #window = options[:target] ||= "new"
    unless target.downcase.start_with?("http://","https://")
      link = "http://" + target.strip
    end
    link_to target, link, :target => "new"   
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

Not sure where I went wrong with this one, the adding and removing of the data are working, but the link_to_add_fields for only the journal/journal_entry form is not responding as it should.  I'm not using the nested_form gem, if that makes a difference...

I'm using Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 1.9.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, The error is that it isn't adding the fields_for partial when I click on link to add the partial so that I can add many "journal" entries on one page.  I don't think the link_to_add_fields is broken because it works on other nested_attribute models, it even works for the nested_attribute model Tenants that is on the same form for leases.

Comment: It works fine for has_many relationship, But I don't know how much it works for has_many through relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the problem is in there somewhere with the :through relationship being on the same partial, but there must be a simple fix for it.  I know we can go many levels deep with the accepts_nested_attributes_for...

Comment: without through relation I wrote answer for your question, see it

Comment: I responded in your answer. Maybe I'm trying to make too much of a shortcut in my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `journal_fields.hrml.erb` file with removing  `fields_for` code blog. for add nested generals for Lease class.

```
 <fieldset style="border:0px none;padding:0px .625em;">
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:200px;font-size:.7em"><%= f.date_select :dated %></td>
          # Your form field
          <td style="width:100px;"><%= g.text_field :account_name, size: 8 %></td>
          <td style="width:100px;"><%= g.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: If I do this how will I tell it to work with the dependent 'g.' model (f's child record in this case the Journal_entries model).  Something like f.object.child.each?.  Maybe if I could make the fileds_for above this to be the child model journal_entries and then have it reference the parent object with something like

`...
<%f.object.parent.date_select :dated %>
<%f.text_field :account_name%>`