# rails how to do f.parent.text_field :name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, fields-for

I need to put fields from journals and journal_entries into one row on a table, and have the ability to add and show many data entry rows in the same view. (ie a table of rows and using link_to_add_fields with accepts_nested_attributes to expand the rows in the table).

There has to be some kind of **f.parent.text_field or f.object.parent.text_field**?

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
<table>
#in a :pm namespace
<%= form_for [:pm, @lease] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :journal_entries do |journal_entries| %>
    <%= render "journal_entry_fields" , f: journal_entries %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add transactions", f, :journal_entries %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

_journal_entry_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
  <tr>
    ## HERE IS WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR <<<<<<<<<<<!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    <td><%= f.parent.text_field :dated %></td>
    <td><%= f.parent.text_field :account_name %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :credit %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :notes %></td>        
  </tr>
</fieldset>
```

My Models

```
class Lease < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :journals, :order => [:dated, :id] #, :conditions => "journals.lease_id = id"
  has_many :journal_entries, :through => :journals  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journal_entries , :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journals ,  :allow_destroy => true    
end

class Journal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lease, :conditions =>  :lease_id != nil   
  has_many :journal_entries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :journal_entries , :allow_destroy => true
end

class JournalEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :journal
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3

I'm trying to see if this is a better solution than the problem faced on: [rails link_to_add_fields not adding fields with has_many :through (with nested form inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381586/rails-link-to-add-fields-not-adding-fields-with-has-many-through-with-nested-f)

I made a different thread because I think it's so drastically different.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve? Why are you adding `<%= f.fields_for :journal_entries do |g| %> ` again in the `_journal_entry_fields.html.erb`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `dated` field? Why are you trying to assign it from the association form? What happens if two different `journal_entries` have two different values for their parent's `dated`? It makes little sense to me...

Comment: Fixed that, it wasn't meant to be there :)  Good catch Manoj.  I'm trying to make it so that I put inputs from the journal model and journal_entry model in the same space.  I know that could lead to confusing the parent if you try to change it when there are multiple children, but that is avoidable with disabling the parent when it has more than one child (allowing it to edit the parent of only the first or last child... That said, is it possible to do some kind of f.parent.text_field :attribute?

Comment: Do you want create journals an their entries while creating the lease? Then you need to use two level deep nesting. Your seems to have it already but you need to add that in your view files. Lexus know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, while I'm creating/updating a lease, I want to be able to create/edit journals and journal_entries for that lease.  I'll try to split them up rather than combine them, it'll probably be more appropriate for the data.  But if there is a lazy way to do it I wouldn't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding about your use-case you want to create journals and its entries in a single form of Lease. So, you can us the fields_for for both of them as below:

```
<table>
  #in a :pm namespace
  <%= form_for [:pm, @lease] do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :journals do |journal| %>
      <%= render "journal_entry_fields" , f: journal %>
    <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add transactions", f, :journals %>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

_journal_entry_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.text_field :dated %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :account_name %></td>
    <%= f.fields_for :journal_entries do |journal_entry| %>
      <td><%= journal_entry.text_field :credit %></td>
      <td><%= journal_entry.text_field :notes %></td>
    <% end %>   
  </tr>
</fieldset>
```

Though you need to initialise the journal entries every time a new record is added dynamically. I can't help you with this right now as I'm not on my PC.

Comment: This is not the solution that I was hoping to get, but probably best to kill the cat there. The f.parent could cause conflicts if the user tries to change one parent record and there were multiple children.  The only problem here is if there are a lot of journal entries it will run way to the right (making an ugly table).  It would be better if there was an easier way to make many rows for the journal_entries.  My solution is similar to this except I resort to divs (and floating) rather than a simple table.  Thank you Manoj!

Comment: Yes I was actually thinking to suggest you the same. By the way, you're welcome! :)

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to initialize that journal entry each time a record is added. I thought it would be done from the controller `@lease = Lease.new;
    journal = @lease.journals.build;
    journal.journal_entries.build`

Comment: No, part of the controller is done as soon as the view page is rendered. So now it is upto helpers or view file how to handle it. I think you can try [this gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for handling dynamic addition of nested fields. And for initializing the journal_entry, you can check if it is already initialized or initialize it as `journal_ent = journal.object.journal_enteries.build journal.object.journal_enteries.blank?` In the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

The RailsCasts model relations are similar to your model relations, although you would need to alter the HTML.

RailsCasts Models: `Survey > Question > Answer`

Your Models: `Lease > Journal > JournalEntry`

Comment: Yeah, I used specifically that episode for a lot of what I have, but for this case it doesn't work. I have other models working, but the magic isn't working for this case.  Any ideas on the f.parent thing?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do the parent thing. I would have tried to nest the models 2 deep instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably [certainly] the most appropriate way, it just seems that the language must support what I'm trying to do [even if it's a little inappropriate].  Thanks Sam